# What do "mug " and "wump" mean in mugwump?

Tags: meaning, etymology

> Professional politicians are masters of equivocation—they are, on most vital issues, mugwumps; they sit on a fence with their **mugs** on one side and their **wumps** on the other. — [Word Power Made Easy](https://books.google.com/books?id=OkToAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=%22they%20sit%20on%20a%20fence%20with%20their%20mugs%20on%20one%20side%20and%20their%20wumps%20on%20the%20other%22&source=bl&ots=0VYdJ6h6OK&sig=ACfU3U2tYhAvAd05GPlUkAMnHCrGkSAqHg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6ypKb2en4AhWIl4kEHSDJDDYQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22they%20sit%20on%20a%20fence%20with%20their%20mugs%20on%20one%20side%20and%20their%20wumps%20on%20the%20other%22&f=false)

> Their independence prompted one 1930s humorist to define a mugwump as "a bird who sits with its **mug** on one side of the fence and its **wump** on the other." — [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mugwump#:%7E:text=Their%20independence%20prompted%20one%201930s%20humorist%20to%20define%20a%20mugwump%20as%20%22a%20bird%20who%20sits%20with%20its%20mug%20on%20one%20side%20of%20the%20fence%20and%20its%20wump%20on%20the%20other.%22)

What do "mug" and "wump" mean in these sentences?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mugwumps#Etymology). 'Mug' is slang for 'face'. You could have looked this up for yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *mugwump* was derived from the Algonquin Indian word *mugquomp*. [See Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mugwump). It is complete coincidence that it can be broken into *mug* and *wump*.

But when people break it up like this, they do it because *mug* means face, and *wump* is a mispronunciation of *rump*, meaning rear end.

Comment: As explained in the Wikipedia link I gave, which the OP could have looked up.

Comment: What is the point in just having answers be ''look it up on Wikipedia'', sometimes the question is intended to stimulate discussion and get different points of view.